# How to Handle C# Data Type Model Validation before get to controller

Tags: c#, json, rest, model-validation

I have this request model in C# WebAPI

```
public class RequestModel{
    public int Code { set; get; }
}
```

then I have API Controller that receive that model as its request body (POST). The problem is, if i run a negative case for testing purpose. I request some json like this

```
{
    "Code": "abcde"
}
```

My request model automatically set its `Code` value to 0. And 0 is a valid value

Is there anyway to handle this case? so I can return some warning / error before it get processed in my controller?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you are getting 0 is because string can't be mapped to int, so it just leaves a default value (which is zero). To validate users input you can use attributes.

Try something like this:

```
public class RequestModel
{
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "*Your warning*")]
    public int Code { set; get; }
}
```

Than in your controller you can check if model state is valid and respond properly. Basically in the beginning of your method in controller you should write something like this:

```
if(!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // Return errors for example
}
else
{
    // Something else
}
```

There is a more elegant way to do such kind of validation. You can simply make your field nullable (`int?`) and delegate all validation work to [fluent validator](https://fluentvalidation.net/). It will run the validation before you'll get in controller and automatically return BadRequest if something goes wrong. Example of fluent validator for your model:

```
public class RequestModelValidator : AbstractValidator<RequestModel>
{
    public RequestModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(m => m.Code).NotNull().WithMessage("*Your msg*");
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh right, `Range` model validation does the job.. Thanks

Comment: @Neistow I believe FluentValidation is not responsible for automatically returning `BadRequest` when validation fails. That should be caused by an `[ApiController]` attribute above the controller [according to the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#automatic-http-400-responses). Although maybe FluentValidation also has a feature for this.

Answer (score 1):

Change your model to this:

```cs
public class RequestModel 
{
    [Required]
    public int? Code { set; get; }
}
```

`Code` will default to null when a value that can't be parsed is received. If you perform model validation it will make sure that `Code` is not null.

Answer (score 0):

If you send a string, in a property that should naturally receive an integer, the complete object will arrive null in its controller, there will be no conversion of the string to zero, as you mentioned.

A practical example:

Class model:

```
public class RequestModel
{
    public int Code { set; get; }
}
```

Your controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

public class Test: Controller
{
    [HttpPost("/test")]
    public IActionResult Test([FromBody] RequestModel requestModel)
    {
        if (requestModel == null)
        {
            return BadRequest("Invalid request");
        }
        return Ok(requestModel);
    }
}
```